# How to disable a particular row section when selected using arrow keys?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I disabled mouse selection of wpf datagrid row using the following style. But still I'm able to select the row using up / down arrow keys. How to disable it?

```
<Style x:Key="rowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
   <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `PreviewKeyDown` event and for keys `Key.Up` and `Key.Down` set `e.Handed - true;`